# could not find function "clean" in R, it was fine when I ran it earlier today

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a beginner in R programming, I am facing an issue with the below code:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(qdap)

atiire_details <- c()
for(i in 1:2){
        html_pages1<-read_html(paste('E:\\Term 1\\Data collections\\assignmentData\\',i,'.html',sep = ''))
                details <- html_nodes(html_pages1,'dl:nth-child(22)')
        wp1<-html_text(details)
                wp1<-gsub("\n","",wp1)
        wp1<-str_trim(clean(wp1))       # Problem function here!
                if(!(length(wp1)==0)){
                if(!(wp1=='Take-out Yes')){
                        atiire_details[i]<-wp1     
                }}}

df<-data.frame()
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(atiire_details))
out <- capture.output(unique(df$atiire_details))
cat("My title", out, file="E:\\R\\op1.txt", sep="n", append=TRUE)
```

I keep getting the below error:

> Error in clean(wp1) : could not find function "clean"

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are several `CRAN` packages with a function `clean`. What package does yours come from?

Comment: I am just looking to clean the scraped data. Like I said in my question it was fine today morning and 1 system restart and now I get this error.

Comment: OK,maybe with `qdap::clean(wp1)`.

Comment: Another possibility is that yesterday you ran one the versions of `R` for which `Java` in your system works and today you are running the other `R` (32 or 64 bits).

Comment: By the way, I used remove.packages(c("qdap", "reshape2")) and reinstalled qdap package again in RStudio. It worked :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I used remove.packages(c("qdap", "reshape2")) and reinstalled qdap package again in RStudio. It worked :) Thanks for the help